# ASP.NET GUI-friendly Build tools

Tags: asp.net, msbuild, build

I am new to .NET programming. We are a team of 4 members developing a web based application.

We will begin our development once the Requirement Specification and other formalities are 
completed.

As suggested in this forum we are planning to use Visual SVN for source control. We are not 
aware of Build tools, we heard that MSBuild and NAnt are some build tools. Please 
clarify, why should we need build tools? Any book or site to learn the build process?

We heard that MSBuild and NAnt are command-line based build tools. Can we use GUI based 
build tools?

**(Before development, we are advised to get a complete knowledge of UML, 
Source control, Build tools. We got enough information about UML and Source control from
Stackoverflow. We wish to gather information about Build Tools ).**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Or have a look at [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder.aspx) as a stand-alone desktop build tool, or [FinalBuilder Server](http://www.finalbuilder.com/finalbuilder-server.aspx) as the same, but server-based.

Marc

Answer (score 3):

We are starting to use [FinalBuilder](http://www.finalbuilder.com/).

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [VisualBuild](http://www.kinook.com/VisBuildPro/).

Answer (score 1):

I've used all the build tools mentioned and none are even close to being as good as [rake](http://www.tobinharris.com/past/2008/11/4/getting-started-with-rake-on-net/). Below is everything you will need to build your solution and run your unit(mbunit) tests. If you are using a different unit testing framework, they are easy to swap. The only part you'll need to worry about is tying this into a build server (super easy) and getting it to pull from whatever source control you are using (also not difficult).

Here is all you need to do to get each of your projects buildings.

1. Install ruby (one click installer [here](http://www.ruby-lang.org/en/downloads/))
2. Add a file called "Rakefile.rb" to your solution
3. Copy the template from below
4. Go to your solution from the command line, type "rake" and hit enter

Here is the template that will get you started.

DOT_NET_PATH = "C:/Windows/Microsoft.NET/Framework/v3.5/"

SOLUTION = "YOUR_SOLUTION_HERE.sln"

CONFIG = "Debug"

MBUNIT_PATH = "C:/pROGRAMS/Gallio/Gallio.Echo.exe"

TEST_NAME = "NAME_OF_TEST_PROJECT_HERE"

task :default => ["build:all"]

namespace :build do

task :all => [:compile, :test]

desc "Use MSBuild to build the solution: '#{SOLUTION}'"

task :compile do

```
sh "#{DOT_NET_PATH}msbuild.exe /p:Configuration=#{CONFIG} #{SOLUTION}"
```

end

desc "Use Gallio to run the MbUnit tests"

task :test => [:compile] do

```
sh "#{MBUNIT_PATH} /no-echo-results test/#{TEST_NAME}/bin/Debug/#{TEST_NAME}.dll"
```

end

end

Comment: I can send you the actual rake file if you have any issues. The code support in the MarkDown editor doesn't like Ruby :(

Also, I am not a pro with this. I don't know ruby. It was just really easy to work with and will probably save you a lot of time.

Comment: so kind of you.can i contact you through your mail id if you have no issues ?

Answer (score 1):

I think a lot of build tools are built into Visual Studio Team Server (VSTS). 
It handles not only your source code protection, but you can have a "build machine". 
NAnt is cool not only for builds, but other scripting tasks.

Neal